# jsoup HTML fragment detection

Tags: jsoup, html-parsing, html-parser

I'm parsing a html fragment without knowing that this is a fragment.
I use the jsoup HTML parser.
For example:

```
    String html = "<script>document.location = \"http://example.com/\";</script>";
    Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
    System.out.println(document.html());
```

Output:

```
<html>
   <head>
     <script>document.location = "http://example.com/";</script>
   </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

Question: Is there a way to know that the `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tags were added by Jsoup and were not in the original html fragment?

Update:

I also tried to enable the errors tracking:

```
Parser parser = Parser.htmlParser();
parser.setTrackErrors(500);
Document document = parser.parseInput(html, "example.com");
ParseErrorList errors = parser.getErrors();
```

But I get an empty list of errors.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this would be to parse it both as XML and as HTML, and compare the element counts of both results. The [XML parser](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/parser/Parser.html#xmlParser()) does not automatically add elements, whereas the HTML parser automatically adds missing optional tags and performs other normalization.

Here's an example:

```java
@Test public void detectAutoElements() {
    String bare = "<script>One</script>";
    String full =
       "<html><head><title>Check</title></head><body><p>One</p></body></html>";

    assertTrue(didAddElements(bare));
    assertFalse(didAddElements(full));
}

private boolean didAddElements(String input) {
    // two passes, one as XML and one as HTML. XML does not vivify missing/optional tags
    Document html = Jsoup.parse(input);
    Document xml = Jsoup.parse(input, "", Parser.xmlParser());

    int htmlElementCount = html.getAllElements().size();
    int xmlElementCount = xml.getAllElements().size();
    boolean added = htmlElementCount > xmlElementCount;

    System.out.printf(
      "Original input has %s elements; HTML doc has %s. Is a fragment? %s\n",
      xmlElementCount, htmlElementCount, added);

    return added;
}
```

This gives the result:

```text
Original input has 2 elements; HTML doc has 5. Is a fragment? true
Original input has 6 elements; HTML doc has 6. Is a fragment? false
```

Depending on your need, you could potentially extend this to more deeply compare the two document structures.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. errors.size() is 0

Comment: Right, sorry, missing optional tags aren't considered errors by the parser. I updated my answer to use a different approach of comparing XML to HTML tree builds, which does work. It might be worth thinking about adding "soft" errors for optional tags as I think that could be useful to track.

Comment: Have you added it to the new version that was released in July?